# get key value for each single array element

Tags: php, arrays

```
$arr = ['night' => 'black', 'sun' => 'light', 'she' => 'gold'];

foreach ($arr as $el) {
    echo ... . '<br>';
}
```

result should be:

night
sun
she

Thanks

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $key => $el)`.. Then echo the `$key` variable

Comment: `foreach ($arr as $key => $val)` probably is what you are looking for. Or `array_keys()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can print key name like this:

```
$arr = ['night' => 'black', 'sun' => 'light', 'she' => 'gold'];

foreach ($arr  as $key => $el) {
    echo  $key. ' <br>';
}
```

Output:

```
night 
sun 
she
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
<?php $array_keys = array_keys($your_array);
```

Comment: Implode the keys with <br> as the glue

Answer (score 0):

try this

`$key` contain all your array key and `$value` contain all your value

```
$arr = ['night' => 'black', 'sun' => 'light', 'she' => 'gold'];

foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key."=".$value."<br>";
}
```

Comment: output is not as desired

Comment: i just display both  key and value. thanks for review.